# Example of zero diameter on a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I want to find an example of an open ball in a metric with $diam(A)=0$ ,$A=B(x_{0},r)$

my example , which i am not sure if it is correct:

$(\mathbb{R},\left | \cdot  \right |) $  and $A=B(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{n})$

then with a triangle inequality we can easily see that $diam(A)\leq \frac{2}{n}$ if $n \to \infty  \Rightarrow  diam(A)\leq 0  \Rightarrow  diam(A)=0 $

does this example do the job ?, is there a more interesting one?

Comment: The formula $A = B(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ does not give a well-defined definition of $A$: changing the value of $n$ changes $A$.

Comment: sorry you are right i meant 1/2 but i forgot to change it when i copy paste 1/n

Comment: It's still not well-defined.

Comment: @LeeMosher is right. And as a further hint, if $diam(A) = 0$, how many points can there be in $A$. (And if you hadn't realized it already, you're going to have to construct a "non-standard" metric space for your example -- this can't happen in your usual  $\mathbb R$.)

Comment: i dont get it, why ?

Comment: @JonathanZ supports MonicaC  only one point? how is that an open ball?

Comment: You said you want an example of **an open ball** $A$ with diameter $0$. If $n=3$ then $A=B(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3})$ is an open ball of diameter $\frac{2}{3}$ that contains the point $.8$. If $n=1000$ then $A=B(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{1000})$ is an example of an open ball of diameter $\frac{2}{1000}$ that does not contain the point $.8$. So those two assignments of $A$ are *not equal to each other*, because  they don't contain the same points, therefore you have not provided *an open ball*.

Comment: Can you construct a metric space where an open ball has only one point?

Comment: Hint: Diameter of a set is 0 implies that set is singleton

Comment: should i take the $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty }$ ?

Comment: @Infinity_hunter yes but a point is not an open ball

Comment: @Petros K In real metric space any finite set is closed, so an open ball whose diameter is 0 in real metric space is impossible

Comment: You need to stop trying to construct a set in the metric space $\mathbb R$ -- it can't happen there. As an example of the kind of thing you need to do (but which isn't a solution to your question), consider the __metric space__ $[0,1]$, with the usual metric. Then $B(1,\frac{1}{3})$ is the set $(\frac{2}{3},1]$ -- which probably seem weird the first time you see it, what with the "$]$", but that is an open ball in that metric space.

Comment: should i consider the distinct metric space where {${x_{0}}$} is open ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "distinct metric space".

Comment: Consider metric space $X = \{0,1\}$ with the metric $d(1,0) = 1 \,, d(0,0) = d(1,1) = 0$, then the open ball of radius $0.5$ centred at $1$ contains only one point.

Comment: the distinct metric space  i mean that $d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x\neq y \\ 
 0& \text{ if } x=y 
\end{cases}$

Comment: @PetrosK - YES, that's great. In English (American) that's called "the discrete metric".

Comment: English in not my native so i didnt know, ok now i get it thank you very much

Comment: Yes, your English is great, and the words "distinct" and "discrete" are easy to confuse! I just wanted to make sure you came out of here using the correct math term. And by the way, make sure you specify a radius less than $1$ if you use this for your answer.

Comment: By the way, your answer and TheSilverDoe's answer point out that you get such an example by either playing with the underlying set __or__ by picking a different $d(\cdot, \cdot)$ function. Changing either of them gets you a different metric space with possibly different properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{N}$ with the usual metric defined by $d(n,m)=|n-m|$. Then the open ball $B(1,1)$ of center $1$ and of radius $1$ is equal to $B(1,1)=\lbrace 1 \rbrace$, so it has diameter $0$.

Comment: why $B(1,1)=\lbrace 1 \rbrace$ ? is this true?

Comment: The elements of $B(1,1)$ are all the elements $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|n-1|<1$ (i.e. such that the distance from $1$ to $n$ is *strictly* less than $1$). Of course, only $1$ satisfies this property.

Comment: if $n=1/2$ it satisfies the property $1/2<1$

Comment: $1/2$ does not belong to $\mathbb{N}$ ($\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of positive integers...)

Comment: oooh ok now i get it

Comment: then why you get down voted?

Comment: @PetrosK Some people are happy to downvote correct answers, without explanation :) It happens all the time ! Your question also has been downvoted...

Comment: ok i see ,thank you this  was also very helpful to me ,i dont mind that my question got down voted i just wanna learn

Comment: You are welcome !

Comment: I downvoted it because I think the OP was learning more by thinking about and responding to the comments than by being given a complete answer. I know that view isn't exactly supported by the website, so I'm being a bit of an old crank here. But yes, @PetrosK, this answer is 100% correct too.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thanks for the comment, at least you explain your downvote. And actually I agree with you that complete answers are in some cases rather useless ; but to defend myself, I also gave a very succint answer, so that the OP has to think a little bit about it.

Comment: Yes, this one worked out well. The OP now has multiple valid answers. I think part of that is due to Petros's genuine desire to learn, and not just fish for a homework answer. I might be getting jaded! Regardless, I now wish I could undo my downvote, but the software prevents me. If you're feeling sneaky, you could make a (trivial) edit to your answer and I would then be allowed to change my vote. :-)

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Haha, I am not sneaky enough :) By the way, since your downvote has been justified and I understood it, I accept it ! This is how the website works :)

Comment: Well, I'm upvoting your comments to make up for it :)